# How can I prioritise spacings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

So say I have a view with 2 textboxes, each having some text in them. This text can go over multiple lines. Now let's say we have a language that takes a lot of space, because of longer words and such.

How can I tell my `TextBlock`s to prioritise taking their padding/margin before they start cutting off their text? (I have margin and padding in place to make it look nicer, but I am willing to do away with them if that means the text fits).

Also, if possible, can I say that these 2 `TextBlock`s should take padding from the first `TextBlock`, and if it isn't enough yet, to take padding from the second `TextBlock`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the issue is? I can only imagine this being a problem if you have **fixed** width `TextBlock` or containers.

Comment: @MikeEason yes indeed my `TextBlock` is fixed width, and wraps to multiple lines if needed. But, as this is a side menu button, I can't go the easy way and make it scroll. It has to fit everything in the space that it is given.

Comment: How about removing the fixed width on the `TextBlock` and moving the fixed width to the container (the sidebar), then, use `TextWrapping` on your `TextBlock` and any text that is too large to fit onto one line will be wrapped within the bounds of the side bar.

Comment: Yes my text does wrap now, but the design dictates I also have some padding/margin and I'd like to know if I can tell my `TextBlock` to take that space before it starts to cut off text.

Comment: As far as I am aware, I don't think that's possible. Well, it probably is but it'd be **very difficult and tedious**. I don't mean to offend you but it sounds to me like the design has been based around the assumption of **English** text, this is obviously a stupid design because English isn't the only language. In my opinion you're better off giving the designer the middle finger and using a scrollbar. **The problem is the design**.